# Is Euler's lemma of fluid mechanics a nonlinear version of Liouville's theorem of ODEs?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, fluid-dynamics

> **Liouville's Theorem** Consider the following linear system of ordinary differential equations:  $$\tag{1}
>  \dot{\mathbf{x}}=A(t)\mathbf{x}(t).$$ Let $\mathbf{x}_1, \mathbf{x}_2,
>  \ldots, \mathbf{x}_n$ be solutions of (1). Define the *Wronskian
>   determinant* to be  $$W(t)=\det \begin{bmatrix} \mathbf{x}_1 &
>  \mathbf{x}_2 & \ldots & \mathbf{x}_n\end{bmatrix}.$$ Then we have the
>   following differential relation for $W(t)$: $$\tag{L}
>  \dot{W}(t)=\verb+trace+\, A(t)\,\cdot\,W(t).$$

Compare with a lemma due to Euler which I encountered in a course of fluid mechanics I am attending. Here $\mathbf{x}$ refers to Eulerian coordinates and $\mathbf{y}$ refers to Lagrangian coordinates.

> **Euler's Lemma** Let $\mathbf{u}(\mathbf{x}, t)$ be the velocity field of a fluid flow $\mathbf{\Phi}(\mathbf{y}, t)$, meaning that:
>   $$\begin{array}{cc} \displaystyle
> \begin{cases} \dot{\mathbf{x}}(t)=\mathbf{u}(\mathbf{x}(t), t) \\ \mathbf{x}(0)=\mathbf{y}\end{cases}, & \mathbf{x}(t)=\mathbf{\Phi}(\mathbf{y}, t)\end{array}.$$
>   Denote with $J$ the Jacobian of the deformation gradient, that is 
>   $$J(\mathbf{y}, t)=\det D_{\mathbf{y}}\mathbf{\Phi}(\mathbf{y}, t).$$
>   Then we have the following differential relation for $J$:
>   $$\tag{E}\frac{dJ}{dt}(t)=(\verb+div+\,\mathbf{u})\,J.$$

Even if it is formulated with the language of fluid mechanics, this lemma is essentially a result in ordinary differential equations, just like Liouville's theorem. My question is if Euler's lemma can be viewed as a nonlinear version of Liouville's theorem and if either one of the two results can be derived from the other.

Thank you for reading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nonlinear form of Liouville's theorem is also found in the literature under the name of Liouville's theorem. See [these notes](http://www.math.duke.edu/~odiaz/liouville.pdf), where Example 3.1 (the linear form that you stated) is obtained as a special case of Lemma 3.2 (which is what you call Euler's lemma above). Another, very thorough, source is Hartman's book *Ordinary differential equations*, chapters IV and V.

Indeed, one of its principal applications of Liouville's theorem is to [Hamiltonian systems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville's_theorem_(Hamiltonian)) which are typically nonlinear.