# Differentiable curve of matrices such that the derivative at 0 has trace equal to zero.

Tags: linear-algebra, derivatives, differential-geometry

Suppose that $\epsilon > 0$, $\gamma: (-\epsilon,\epsilon) \to \text{End}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ is a differentiable curve of matrices such that $\text{det}(\gamma(t)) = 1$ for all $t\in(-\epsilon,\epsilon)$ and $\gamma(0) = I$. Show that $(D\gamma)_0$ has trace zero.

I know that $\gamma(0+h) = \gamma(0)+(D\gamma)_0(h)+\epsilon(h)$ however,
I don't know how to calculate the derivative since I don't know the function $\gamma$ explicitly and I am not really sure if there are any properties of the trace that could help me.

Comment: Interesting. [This theorem of Liouville](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/308255/8157) should do the trick. Use it to differentiate $\det\gamma(t)$, which you know has derivative zero.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro mmm we haven't seen that theorem by Liouville so I don't think that we are able to use it. However, I was thinking that you could use the chain rule in the following way $0=(D1)_0 = D(det\circ\gamma)_0 = (Ddet)_{Id}\circ (D\gamma)_0$,my problem then would be that I think I've heard that the derivative of the determinant is the trace, but I am not sure if this is true.

Comment: That's it; the derivative of the determinant is the trace in some sense. Since the derivative of the determinant here is zero, the trace is zero. This is the idea

Answer (score 3):

Recall that the characteristic polynomial $p_A(t) = \det(tI-A) = t^n -\text{tr}(A)t^{n-1}+\dots+(-1)^n\det A$. From this you should be able to get that
$$\frac d{ds}\Big|_{s=0} \det (I+sA) = \text{tr}(A).$$
(Of course, you can get it explicitly by expanding the determinant, too.)